# GCP Dataflow pipeline no json rows being read/processed

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Based on the WordCount Example, I am trying to read my own json data (instead of the shakespear txts).

I am running the pipeline with:

```
mvn compile exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=myPkg.myClass  -Dexec.args=" \
 --project=myProj \
 --stagingLocation=gs://myBkt/stage \
 --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner \
 --output=gs://myBkt/output/out \
 --defaultWorkerLogLevel=DEBUG"
```

the output from the console is as follows:

```
<date> com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 68 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
<date> myPkg$GroupPublished apply
<date> myPkg$GroupPublished apply
INFO: GroupPublished/JsonToDatePosPlatKeyFn.out [PCollection]
<date> myPkg main
```

**main**

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadJson").from(options.getInputFile())) 
        .apply(new GroupPublished())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new FormatAsStringFn()))
        .apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteCounts").to(options.getOutput()));
}
```

**GroupPublished transformation**

```
static class GroupPublished extends PTransform<PCollection<String>,
        PCollection<KV<DatePosPlatKey, Long>>> {
    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<DatePosPlatKey, Long>> apply(PCollection<String> lines) {
        PCollection<DatePosPlatKey> keyList
                = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new JsonToDatePosPlatKeyFn()));

        PCollection<KV<DatePosPlatKey, Long>> keysCounted =
                keyList.apply(Count.<DatePosPlatKey>perElement());

        return keysCounted;
    }
}
```

**json row processing**

```
static class JsonToDatePosPlatKeyFn extends DoFn<String, DatePosPlatKey>{
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(c.element());
        for (JsonNode jsonFact : root) {
            DatePosPlatKey key = new DatePosPlatKey(...construct...);
            ...manipulate...
            c.output(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**data class**

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public static class DatePosPlatKey { ... }
```

**stuff I've checked so far:**

- adding `defaultWorkerLogLevel` doesn't seem to make any difference to the console output
- renaming the json file throws an error, so I know its been seen by TextIO
- the json files have data in the format: `{...}\n{...}\n...`
- no logging or dataflow job appears in the google cloud console

how can I better debug a complete lack of data?
can you see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Does the same job work using the Direct Runner?

Comment: Also, if you have a Dataflow job ID, I can look it up and see what might have gone wrong. But running in Direct Runner should always be the first option.

Comment: @jkff the DirectPipelineRunner doesn't change the output. Using the Blocking runner, there is no Dataflow job instantiated (i assume google doesn't start provisioning vms, until there is some data detected)

Comment: If the job doesn't run at all in direct runner, there's likely something very wrong in the job setup. What exactly happens in direct runner - does the program complete without having produced the desired effect? does the program hang indefinitely? If there's no Dataflow job ID printed to console, then either the logging is set up wrong, or you have network issues and the program is hanging while trying to send the job specification to the Dataflow service. Try running the program under debugger and taking a thread snapshot to see where it's stuck?

Comment: the program runs and completes successfully (in a few seconds). i think we can rule out network issues, because the wordcount example runs just fine and the pom i use is exactly the same (i just added jackson for JsonNode). i debugged wordcount and my dataflow side by side, locally and noticed that it breaks at a breakpoint in GroupPublished (PTransform), but not in JsonToDatePosPlatKeyFn (DoFn). to me, that says that there are no rows to process, but i dont know how to look into the PCollections to see what the data in them looks like, if there is any in there at all

Comment: Hmm. I don't see `--inputFile` specified in your invocation. Are you specifying it correctly?

Comment: yep, it uses the @Default, like in wordcount. that bit is definately working becuase if i change the name, it throws a file not found error

Comment: Some more thoughts: 1) print the input file name in the program and manually confirm that this is the right file and that the file is, in fact, non-empty (stupid, I know, but better safe than sorry) 2) log something in JsonToDatePosPlatKeyFn.processElement 3) check that the file is in UTF-8 encoding (TextIO.Read only supports UTF-8) 4) set breakpoints in TextIO.TextBasedReader.startReading() and readNextRecord(). If all else fails, then I'm honestly at a loss, but I'd be happy to investigate if you can provide a full example I could reproduce (code and sample data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon offline discussion it turned out the code was missing a call to `p.run()`, so the pipeline was only constructed but not executed.